# I am unsure whether this is a binomial or normal distribution question and how to go about solving it?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

The question "Develop a hypothesis, and constructed appropriate null and alternative/experimental hypothesis.
a) Hyacinth bulbs are sold to a retailer in packs of 100 which claim to have equal numbers of bulbs producing blue and pink flowers. Test at the 10% level of significance whether the retailer has a right to complain that there are not equal numbers of each colour. Find the critical region for the test."

Would anyone be able to help point me in the right direction or show an example of what is being asked?
Thank you and I'm sorry if this seems basic.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Josh.  *Under certain assumptions,* the correct distribution is Binomial, but--as you surely know--the Normal approximation will work fine for the values given in this problem, so take your pick.  You can find many, many examples here on CV.  Good key words include "binomial," "test", "one-sample," "normal," and "proportion."  Concerning those assumptions: the retailer is not explicitly stating the packs are filled completely randomly. If they assert the numbers are "equal," then the best test of that is to check whether there are 50 bulbs of each color.